# PhantomJS really slow on Mac OS X

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS, I really like it but it is really slow... 
Simple code for opening http://www.google.com and exiting takes 47347 ms which is terribly slow..

If I try to run with "sudo" it takes 1282 which is 40x speed up, why this is happening?
I am using phantom 1.8.1, Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sudo part, but maybe this works:
https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/126#issuecomment-75944613

> It's the socket connection between the phantomjs module and it's dependency, shoe.
>
> You can manually edit shoe yourself. Go into node_modules/phantom/shoe/index.js and change line 8 to read
>
> ```
> var server = sockjs.createServer({
>         heartbeat_delay : 200
> });
> ```

Comment: I installed phantomjs via homebrew, any idea where I can change the settings above? its running really slow.

Comment: Just reinstalled with `npm phantom phantomjs -g`. Couldn't find the line `sockjs` either. Running phantomjs 2.1.1.

Comment: I checked out my old working directory, just to find out my answer was about [a node wrapper for phantomjs](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) v0.7.2, not the phantomjs itself. Sorry for the confusion.
I was using nightmarejs and it was dependent on this wrapper.